# I am generating a style listing dynamically. What is the jquery function to add a class to the first level li?

Tags: jquery, css

```
     <ul class ="menu">
  <li>testlevel11
      <ul>
         <li>testleve111</li>
          <li>testleve112</li>
      </ul>
</li>
<li>testlevel12
     <ul>
         <li>testleve121</li>
          <li>testleve122
             <ul>
                <li>testleve1221</li>
                <li>testleve1222</li>
           </ul>
          </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>tsetlevel13</li></ul>
```

I want to add the css class to the first level li in below list style. What is the jquery function to add a class to the first level li?

Answer (score 2):

You basically want to select the child-li's of your ul using the [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) and jQuery's [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method.

```
jQuery('ul.menu > li').addClass('your-class');
```

Comment: That code will add `your-class` to every li, not just the top-level one. To restrict it to the top-level one you'd need to either add the class of the first-level ul, or use $('ul:first > li').addClass('your-class');​

Answer (score 1):

```
​$('.menu > li').addClass('your-class');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

This will add a class of 'yourClass' to all of the top-level `li`s in the menu `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery selecter `.addClass("your classes")`

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

```
$("ul > li").addClass("classnames seprated by space");
```